# Rearrange Acos equation for b

Tags: trigonometry

Apologies for what is probably an easy question but my mind has gone black, I need to rearrange this equation for $b$:
\begin{equation}
a=\left(\frac{180}{\pi}\right)\arccos \left(\frac{b-cd}{b}\right)
\end{equation}

Thanks in advance

Comment: damn, clicked on the wrong tag! sorry! what would it go under?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
a &= \frac{180}{\pi}\arccos\frac{b-cd}{b}\\
\arccos\left(1-\frac{cd}{b}\right) &= \frac{a\pi}{180}\\
1-\frac{cd}{b} &= \cos\frac{a\pi}{180}\\
\frac{cd}b &= 1-\cos\frac{a\pi}{180}\\
b &= \frac{cd}{1-\cos\frac{a\pi}{180}}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Was it originally an $\arccos$ in the inital question or $\cos$ multiplied by a constant $A$?

Comment: I also would like @bolt19 to confirm. The above was based on how WolframAlpha interpreted `a = Acos((b - (c * d)) / b) * 180 / PI`

Comment: it was arccos in the initial question, and thanks, I will use it in the future!

Comment: Excellent, well spotted @peterwhy